# How do toroidal and linear aerospike nozzles compare?

Tags: engine-design, aerospike

What are the pro's and con's of toroidal and linear aerospike engines with respect to each other? When does one choose one design over the other?

A linear aerospike is characterized by multiple linearly aligned engines on each side of a prism, the cross section of which is formed by an "inverted bell nozzle". An example for this design is the [Rocketdyne XRS-2200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_XRS-2200).

A toroidal aerospike consists either of a single combustion chamber with a spike or plug placed within the annulus, cf. [Rocketdyne J-2T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerospike_engine#/media/File:Annular-Aerospike.jpg), or multiple bell-shaped nozzles aimed towards a spike in their center, cf. [Firefly's abandoned plans](https://newatlas.com/firefly-alpha-aerospike-launch-vehicle/32892/).

Comment: Please provide at least a link to description of these types, and ideally links to successful products which use each.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the suggestion, please see the edit.

Comment: IMHO it's packaging of the engine in the ship, but not sure how to confirm.

Comment: it's easier to cool the thin end of a linear aerospike, but it weighs more (because it's not a square root as it is in the toroid)